# cordova admob plus not showing ads

Tags: javascript, admob, cordova-admob

I am trying to show a rewarded ad (with admob) plus when my function is called. I tried with Interstitial too but nothing shown. I am using google test ads and ID

```
let rewarded;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
    await admob.start().then(() => {
        console.log('AdMob started.');
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));

    rewarded = new admob.RewardedAd({
        adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917'
    });
}, false)


function Reward() {
    rewarded.on('load', (evt) => {
        await rewarded.load();
    })

    rewarded.load()
    rewarded.show()
}
```

I have tried many modifications but still no ad is displayed. Maybe the problem is that I need something in the config.xml file
Please help

Answer (score 0):

try `var rewarded;` instead of

> let rewarded;

------------------------ or ------------------------

I suggest

> admob.rewarded = new admob.RewardedAd (...)

```
function Reward() {
  admob.rewarded.on('load', (evt) => {
    await admob.rewarded.load();
  })

  admob.rewarded.load()
  admob.rewarded.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a slight error on the documentation. Here is what i did to make mine work.

```
let rewarded;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, false);

function deviceIsReady(){
admob.start();    
rewarded = new admob.RewardedAd({
   adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-8716485588609849/xxxxxxxxxx',
});
rewarded.load();
}

document.addEventListener('admob.rewarded.dismiss', async () => {
  rewarded.load();
});


document.addEventListener('admob.rewarded.loadfail', async () => {
  rewarded.load();
});
```

Hope this helps you and anyone.